# Gráfico de barras para distintas variables cualitativas

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una tabla con columnas que representan a variables categóricas, con valores 0 y 1, tal que así

[image: Tabla]

Lo que necesito es hacer un gráfico de barras para cada columna, donde se muestren las cantidades de 0 y 1, pero que se vean todos en el mismo gráfico.

Lo único que logro es hacer el gráfico para cada columna, pero no juntarlos.

El código que uso es, por ejemplo para la columna A

`barplot(table(datos$A))` y obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera agregar las otras columnas en el mismo gráfico.

Estoy usando RStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer problema es como construir los datos que sean "entendibles" por el `barplot`:

```
mx <- do.call(rbind, lapply(datos, table))
mx

   0  1
A 20 80
B 41 59
C 31 69
```

Los datos son generados sinteticamente y no coincidirán con los tuyos pero la idea es esta 1) Aplicamos `table` a cada columna 2) unimos en una matriz por fila los resultados obtenidos.

Lo siguiente es la gráfica:

```
colours = c("red","blue", "green")

barplot(mx,
        beside = TRUE, 
        col = colours,
        ylim = c(0,max(mx)*1.5)
        )


legend("top",
       c("A","B","C"), 
       lty = c(1,1,1),
       col = colours,
       ncol = 3,
       bty = "n")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.
Muy práctica la solución. El código que muestras no genera lo que en realidad busco, pero lo modifiqué un poco y logré lo que quería.
De verdad muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Si te le animas a `ggplot()` puedes resolver todo bastante fácil también y con mejores formas de configurar la gráfica:

```
library("tidyverse")

datos %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(A, B, C)) %>% 
  group_by(name, value) %>% 
  summarise(cantidad = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=name, fill=factor(value), y=cantidad)) +
    geom_col(position=position_dodge(width=1)) +
    scale_fill_discrete(name = "1 y 0")+
    labs(title = paste("Titulo"), 
       subtitle = paste("Subtitulo") , 
       caption = "Fuente", 
       y = "Leyenda Y", 
       x = "Leyenda X"
  )
```

La idea es "expandir" tus datos de forma vertical con `pivot_longer()` para terminar sumarizando por la etiqueta y el valor 1 o 0. El resto es la configuración de la gráfica en sí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta solución es realmente elegante, muy bonita.
Voy a revisar con más detalle el código para entenderlo, pues la verdad no me revisado mucho el ggplot().
De todas maneras muchas gracias por tu respuesta.